# aws ec2 describe-addresses won't show some instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm scripting some stuff with `aws ec2 describe-addresses`, but, for some reason, some instances won't be returned by it.

Example:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-addresses --filter=Name=instance-id,Values=i-xxxxx 
{
    "Addresses": []
}
```

The given `instanceId` is valid and has addresses, but it just won't be shown by aws cli.

However, for another instances it seems to work just fine:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-addresses --filter='Name=instance-id,Values=i-yyyyyy'                                           
{
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "PrivateIpAddress": "X.X.X.X",
            "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyy",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-xxxxxx",
            "PublicIp": "Y.Y.Y.Y",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-xxxxxx",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-xxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

The keys I'm using have `EC2FullAccess` policy, so, it doesn't seem to be related to security...

What am I doing wrong? Any tips? Is there any limitations of aws cli that I'm not aware of?

Comment: what if you run it without filter, do all instances show up?

Comment: Nope, some instances are missing...

Comment: ec2-describe-addresses will describe Elastic IP addresses, so only instances with associated Elastic IP will show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is you are not listing the instances, actually listing the Elastic IP Addresses. Probably the missing ones are the ones without Elastic IPs.

So for example the command without the filter will list the EIP list

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses
```

Output:

```
{
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "InstanceId": null,
            "PublicIp": "198.51.100.0",
            "Domain": "standard"
        },
        {
            "PublicIp": "203.0.113.0",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-64d5890a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html

Comment: so, basically, this command only shows instances with elastic ip addresses? How can I get the same thing for instances that don't have it?

Comment: @caarlos0: You can use describe-instances to get all and filter them with association.public-ip: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy: You should create an answer with that first comment.